# SharpMap & BruTile library: Method not found

Tags: c#, tiles, sharpmap

I'm using `SharpMap 1.1` and `BruTile 0.12.0` in my project. when I try to add a Tilelayer to the map the program stops with an unhandled exception of type `System.MissingMethodException`.

```
Map.BackgroundLayer.Add(new TileAsyncLayer(BruTile.Predefined.KnownTileSources.Create(BruTile.Predefined.KnownTileSource.BingHybrid), "OSM"));
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in SharpMap.dll
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void BruTile.Cache.MemoryCache`1..ctor(Int32, Int32)'.

How can i do that without errors?

Comment: Looks like you posted the same question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200165/sharpmap-brutile-library-method-not-found

Comment: Possibly a conflict between the sharpmap/brutile versions and the underlying C# runtime you're trying to use. Can you show your App.config and tell us what builds of brutile and sharpmap you have? Also, can you show us an actual debug output, including the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BruTile has a lot of breaking changes from v0.7.4 to v0.12
You will have to adjust SharpMap's  TileLayer to reflect these.

Comment: Or just use BruTile v0.7.4.4. That is the BruTile version SharpMap v1.1 was developed for.